# Why can't I use flex with <button> elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering, text-alignment

I have the following code in *index.html*

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#count-el {
  font-size: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#increment-btn {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>People entered:</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
<button id="increment-btn">Increment</button>
```

Flex works in all elements except for the `<button>` element. It doesn't center it. Why is that?

Comment: it is working as expected!

Comment: These flex properties don't affect the elements you're applying them to, they affect the content within. The `h1` and `h2` elements themselves are not centered, the content within them is (as implied by the name justify-**content**).

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? It really is doing what it's meant to be doing: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d6v4f081/1/).

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks, I now understand. I added the button element into a div container, and the flex now works. It's all about the invisible margins. How do I close this post by selecting an answer?

Comment: There are no invisible margins. There are just properties affecting different elements/content than you think they were affecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to your button class `margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;` 
should look like that

```
#increment-btn {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: @ths: no, a defined width isn't necessary at all ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d6v4f081/2/)), what's "necessary" is that the element to be centred is not `display: inline` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d6v4f081/3/)).

Comment: @ths it works for me https://codepen.io/savconstantine/pen/QWrdKQy without width

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers display button elements as inline-block by default, so, it won't occupy 100% of parent's width. If you apply width 100% it will center the text, just like h1, h2. If you want to center the button itself you can use margin: 0 auto; property.

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#count-el {
  font-size: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#increment-btn {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>People entered:</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
<button id="increment-btn">Increment</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem you need to read this article:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You should add

```
margin: auto;
display: block;
```

to #increment-btn style.

Other solution is to add a div parent element to the button and add flex style there:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

I made a codepen for you: https://codepen.io/kovtib/pen/vYjgXrP

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#count-el {
  font-size: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#increment-btn {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-inline: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>People entered:</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
<button id="increment-btn">Increment</button>
```

Add margin-inline: auto to your button styles.